# How can I prove equation $3.2$ in the hook-length formula?

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

> [image]

I am following Sagan's book on "Representation of Symmetric Groups" for hook-length formula. An inductive approach was given in the book. I have understood everything before the equation $3.2$ where induction hypothesis has been implemented. Can anybody please clear the step here?

Thanks for your time.